# Storing only \\servername\share\ in new array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, split

I'm building a tool that will allow me to query our AD user object's homedirectory values and the associated file server's home directories for reporting and management purposes.

I've queried AD and stored an array of all of the homedirectory and samaccountname values for the accounts in our two OUs.

Next I've pulled out the `$homedirectory` values and run them through split using regex:

`$ServShare = $Homedirectory -Split '(^\\\\([a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\([a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\)'`

Now I have a long list that is formatted as follows:

> \\servername1\sharename
>   servername1
>   sharename
>   username1
>
> \\servername1\sharename
>   servername1
>   sharename
>   username2
>
> \\servername2\sharename
>   servername2
>   sharename
>   username3
>
> etc...

What I need is to store all of the \servername\sharename values in a new array for further work (unique values, the querying to get the servers/shares I'll need to run `get-childitem` against, etc).

I've checked the data, and even with some variation in the number of folders in the share paths, all of the results I need are on the 1st and 6th lines. So line 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, etc... out of the hundreds of lines of the resulting list.

Yet I'm having trouble getting my mind around pulling those lines out and storing them to use further along. I haven't done much of any work parsing arrays and text, and I'd appreciate a pointer along the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your posted output is stored in an array (`$list`) of strings, you can easily access the data you want and store it into another array.

```
$ArrayOfPaths = $list -match "^\\"
$ArrayOfPaths | Get-Unique  # Lists only unique values
```

Alternatively, you can access the indexes if the target values are at predictable locations within the array. Here they occur after every 5 indexes.

```
$ArrayOfPaths = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $list.count; $i+=5) {
    $list[$i]
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. Yes the target values are at predictable locations, every 5 indexes starting at 1, so 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, etc... However, using the -match argument seems to me to be a better solution as it will work even when the needed values are in unpredictable locations, and I can pipe this into a one-liner that gives me the case-insensitive unique values `$ArrayOfPaths = $ServShare -Match "^\\" | Sort-Object -Unique`

Comment: Actually, I shortened it further based on Order of Operations: `$ServShare = $Homedirectory -Split '(^\\\\([a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\([a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\)' -match "^\\" | Sort-Object -Unique`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but it might help. Use `$ServShare.GetType()` to find out that it is an array.

```
$UncList = @()    # Create an empty array to hold the UNC strings

foreach ($Homedirectory in $HomeDirectories) {
    $ServShare = $Homedirectory -Split '(^\\\\([a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\([a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\)'
    $UncList += $ServShare[1]
}

$UncList
```

Comment: Yes, the list i an array. BaseType System.Array.

Comment: Which element of the ServShare array contains the \\COMPUTERNAME\SHARENAME that you want to add to the `UncList` array? Is it `$ServShare[1]`, or another one?

Comment: It's element 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, etc... There's probably an option for split I'm missing, but the output from split is a list with each output from the split on a separate line, a 1-dimension array as it were, rather than a 2D array with multiple columns.

Comment: @music2myear - What is the result in `$UncList`?